# IDE creates new files with "_" in the beginning of all files

Tags: flutter, android-studio, ide

Can someone explain whats going on, every time I create a new file the IDE is creating the file with the same name but adding underscore "_" in the beginning. I don't even know if the problem is in the AndroidStudio or in the Flutter.
I had no problems before.

Image from the project structure.
[image]

Image inside some new file with underscore:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are files stored by macOS when writing to external drives that aren't capable of storing `extended attributes` in the way AFPS (or formerly HFS+) store them. Those files contain these extended attributes instead. On AFPS you could normally access them with `xattrs`.

*References:*
https://developer.apple.com/support/downloads/Apple-File-System-Reference.pdf
https://eclecticlight.co/2020/10/24/theres-more-to-files-than-data-extended-attributes/

Comment: Thank you very much. You were right, I had an external storage with a different file system. I just reformatted my drive with APFS, and it works fine now. This has also solved another problem I had. Previously, my computer wouldn't start with this external SSD, and I had to unplug it. But now it works fine even in that case. Thank you very much once again!

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad you got these issues solved!

Comment: Ok I understand that now but why the problem was not there before, why now?